# React JS _TypeError: _This.dropdowncounter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As mentioned in the title I'm getting this error and can't figure out why.
I have a child component called SubDropdown like so:

```
class SubDropdown extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.dropdownCounter = this.dropdownCounter.bind(this);
  }

  dropdownCounter() {
      let dataofDropdowns = [];
      let elements = [];
      return elements;
    }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      { this.dropdownCounter() }
      </div>
    )
  }

}
export default SubDropdown;
```

I've stripped it down to this just to find the error.  I bind this to this.dropdownCounter as shown above.

I then load the web page where the parent component is.  And I get this error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.dropdownCounter is not a function`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Sharing parent component:

```
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="add-to-cart">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <CarouselPhotos />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
            <Form>
              <div>
                <Dropdown
                  title="Size"
                  arrayId="selectProduct"
                  list={this.state.selectProduct}
                  resetThenSet={this.resetThenSet}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
              {this.state.isLoading ? (
                <Loader
                type="ThreeDots"
                color="#00BFFF"
                height="100"
                width="100"
                />
              ) : (
                <SubDropdown productInfo={this.state}/>
              )}
              </div>
            </Form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      ) }
  }
```

EDIT: On the first render it works but I have a drop down associated with it so when it attempts to call { this.dropdownCounter() } is when I get the error.

Adding console.log(this.dropdownCounter); inside of dropdownCounter() gives this:

```
dropdownCounter() {
      var result = Object.entries(this.props.productInfo);
      var dataofDropdowns = [];
      var elements = [];

      console.log(this.dropdownCounter);
```

On the second run after I select it that's when I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.dropdownCounter is not a function
The above error occurred in the <App> component:
    in App
```

Comment: Works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/xo6nrlp1o4

Comment: everything looks correct to me.

Comment: Can you share  parent component code where SubDropDown component is being called ?

Comment: Don't forget to pass props to super()

Comment: It works on the initial render but when I have a drop down in the main component so when it re renders after a change that's when I get the error.  Just caught that.  @Chris G

Comment: Unrelated to the error I guess, but it should be `productInfo={this.state}`

Comment: So even with the stripped down component it is failing on the second render?

Comment: Yes it fails.  But I think I did it wrong.  I probably should make it when you click on the dropdown I want then it should call the child component method.  Currently it always calls the component method on render.  On the second render is when it gives that error.  @GarrettMotzner

Comment: and the error is coming from the SubDropdown component? Because as far as I can tell, it should work... So I'm wondering if the error is coming from a different place, and subDropdown is a red herring...

Comment: basicapp.js:63226 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.dropdownCounter is not a function
    at App.<anonymous> (basicapp.js:63226)
    at callCallback (basicapp.js:50749) @GarrettMotzner

Comment: Just to make sure, what happens when you don't call `this.dropdownCounter` at all? (also, maybe log what `this.dropdownCounter` (no parentheses) is before you call it)

Comment: I added it on top to the question.  The first render produces dropdownCounter() with the code.  On the second render it also does the console log but then it exists with the uncaught error. @GarrettMotzner

Comment: so is App calling dropdown counter anywhere? Looks like it isn't being called by SubDropdown.

Comment: No app calls <SubDropdown>  The SubDropdown has:     return(
      <div>
      { this.dropdownCounter() }
      </div> @GarrettMotzner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186890/discussion-between-garrett-motzner-and-fabriciog).